# Align Texts below Button Containers

Tags: html, css

This is how my current page looks:

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjRU6.png)

This is the expected result:

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23LGB.png)

Furthermore, when the screen is minimised and the screen width is reduced, the texts shouldn't look sloppy and out of position. Instead, they should resize and maintain the same position according to the width of the screen.

```
<body>
  <h1>MedConnect</h1>
  <h2>Please select your Role</h2>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <a style="background-color: #A4907C;" href="process_role.php?role=user" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i><span style="font-family: Lora;">User</span></a>
    <a style="background-color: #5A96E3;" href="process_role.php?role=consultant" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-hand-holding-medical"></i><span>Consultant</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="texts">
    <h5>Sign Up as a User on MedConnect</h5>
    <h5>Sign Up as a Consultant on MedConnect</h5>
  </div>

  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/all.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');
    body {
      font-family: Lora;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 100px;
      background-color: #DBE2EF;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    h2 {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .btn-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 50px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }

    .btn-container a {
      width:15%;
    }

    .btn-container a span {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      display: block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

  </style>
```

Comment: Its simple. Just consider your user or consultant button as a box (i.e, if you wrap it in a div) and add the text to the box and use the flex styling

Comment: Can you elaborate in an answer please, with some code if possible?

Comment: I guess Rakibul has done the same thing below, Just compare his and your btn container elements. If you are having similar problem next time try to think of it in boxes this way you can almost solve all the HTML and CSS positioning issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it will be to bring the texts within the `btn-container` so I had to change the markup a little bit and added the required CSS and commented out that were not necessary.

I think you can do the other changes easily from here.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: Lora;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #DBE2EF;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;      
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.btn-container div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 100px;
}

.btn-container a {
  /* width:15%; */
  width: 60%;
}

.btn-container a span {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>MedConnect</h1>
  <h2>Please select your Role</h2>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div>
      <a style="background-color: #A4907C;" href="process_role.php?role=user" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i><span style="font-family: Lora;">User</span></a>
      <h5>Sign Up as a User on MedConnect</h5>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a style="background-color: #5A96E3;" href="process_role.php?role=consultant" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-hand-holding-medical"></i><span>Consultant</span></a>
      <h5>Sign Up as a Consultant on MedConnect</h5>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="texts">
    <h5>Sign Up as a User on MedConnect</h5>
    <h5>Sign Up as a Consultant on MedConnect</h5>
  </div> -->

  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/all.js"></script>
</body>
```